# 2D Collision - Separating Axis Theorem - How to choose the points for checking

Tags: java, vector, collision-detection

I have lately been trying my hand on Collision detection using the Separating Axis theorem, however,  my cubes (I am currently using cubes to try to get the hang of it) rotate while they move and the program should then check if they intersected, how would I go to decide which points/dots/corners I should use at each point in time to check for the min and max coördinates on the vectors used to detect collision.

Thanks in advance,
Mattijn

Comment: Can you share the code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

With SAT based CD I believe you should be projecting all points onto your separating axes.  As the scene evolves you should be changing the axis vectors you use.  These are the normals of the faces in your scene.  As the cubes rotate, the separating axes rotate.  You still need to project each point though.

I think this guy writes up the whole thing pretty well: http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55